# Installing nginx via chef Role is not applying my changes

Tags: chef, chef-solo, knife

I wrote a role to use the default [nginx](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/nginx) cookbook. The role is not applying any of my attributes. It keeps installing nginx 1.2.1.

```
{
  "name": "nginx",

  "json_class": "Chef::Role",
  "chef_type": "role",

  "override_attributes": {
    "nginx": {
      "version": "1.5.13",
      "default_site_enabled": true
    }
  },

  "run_list": [
    "recipe[nginx]"
  ]
}
```

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0):

`default_site_enabled = true` is already the default.

Specifying a version usually doesn't work (might depends on the operating system) with the `install_method = 'package'`, as this is ignored and the current version installed through the package manager (e.g. `apt`).

Thus, all the things that you set won't have any effect.